# Getting null exception in matching userid and password

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a Login Activity based app. And when i am doing Registration(Sign Up), all the data is coming into database successfully but when user is at Login Activity and making attempt to Login then getting a null in Exception.

This is my code,

```
        loginuserid=etloginuserid.getText().toString();
        loginpassword=etloginpassword.getText().toString();
        try
        {
            String storedPassword=db.getPasswordOfThisUser(loginuserid);

            if(loginpassword.equals(storedPassword))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent iwelpage=new Intent(this,WelcomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(iwelpage);
                finish();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username or Password does not match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

And this is my database class activity,

When Creating table,

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        try
        {
            String CREATE_POLLINGDATA_TABLE="CREATE TABLE pollingdata(username TEXT, userid PRIMARY KEY, password TEXT)";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_POLLINGDATA_TABLE);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When retrieving password for the entered userid,

```
public String getPasswordOfThisUser(String loginuserid)
{
    Cursor cursor=db.query("pollingdata", null, " userid=?" , new String[]{loginuserid}, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1)
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "Not Exist";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PASSWORD));
    return password;
}
```

LogCat,

```
10-30 06:03:13.066: E/AndroidRuntime(13692): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 06:03:13.066: E/AndroidRuntime(13692): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-30 06:03:13.066: E/AndroidRuntime(13692):    at com.example.polling.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:47)
10-30 06:03:13.066: E/AndroidRuntime(13692):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
10-30 06:03:13.066: E/AndroidRuntime(13692):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
10-30 06:03:13.066: E/AndroidRuntime(13692):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-30 06:03:13.066: E/AndroidRuntime(13692):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-30 06:03:13.066: E/AndroidRuntime(13692):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-30 06:03:13.066: E/AndroidRuntime(13692):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-30 06:03:13.066: E/AndroidRuntime(13692):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 06:03:13.066: E/AndroidRuntime(13692):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-30 06:03:13.066: E/AndroidRuntime(13692):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-30 06:03:13.066: E/AndroidRuntime(13692):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-30 06:03:13.066: E/AndroidRuntime(13692):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Where i am getting wrong ?

Please help me,

Thanks.

Comment: You could post the exception and stack trace for more information.

Comment: Can you clearly mention where you are getting the null pointer exception..i.e, Activity or Database

Comment: `String storedPassword=db.getPasswordOfThisUser(loginuserid);` here

Comment: Please provide Error Log.

Comment: Please make sure that you initialize db object before call

Comment: I have used try and catch block so, its catching exception that is `null`

Comment: Where have you declared db ??

Comment: @androiduser: Ok i am posting..

Comment: @Shiv what tis line 47 `LoginActivity`?

Comment: @androiduser: LogCat posted

Comment: @shiv r u initialize db object ?

Comment: @Raghunandan: This is line 47 `String storedPassword=db.getPasswordOfThisUser(loginuserid);`

But I got solution and posted my answer :)

Comment: @Shiv: I told you the same thing that have you declared db object..:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved :)

I got my Answer,

I have not written this,

```
db=new DBAdapter(LoginActivity.this);
db.open();
String storedPassword=db.getPasswordOfThisUser(loginuserid);
db.close();
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: your db was not initialized so you get NPE

Comment: @Raghunandan: hmm..yeah :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public String getPasswordOfThisUser(String loginuserid) {
    Cursor cursor = db.query("pollingdata", new String[] { KEY_PASSWORD },
            " userid=?", new String[] { username }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() < 1) {
        cursor.close();
        return "Not Exist";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PASSWORD));
    return password;
}
```

must close cursor before returning the password

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
"CREATE TABLE pollingdata(username TEXT, userid PRIMARY KEY, password TEXT)"
```

is incorrect.
Maybe you should change to

```
"CREATE TABLE pollingdata(username TEXT, userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, password TEXT)"
```

Comment: What if `PRIMARY KEY` is `TEXT` ?

Answer (score 0):

In tha create table statement you have not specified the type of user id.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(cursor.getCount()<1)
{
    cursor.close();
    return "Not Exist";
}
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

to

```
String password="";
if(cursor!=null)
{
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    password= cursor.getString("password");
}
return password;
```